# After printing a random two dimensional array , I need to find the first min and first max in the first row?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

For example, we have a `random 5 x 5 array`
1 5 9 4 2    <=====  //need to find min and max in this row .
6 4 3 7 9-----------            //and then swap their index columns
9 4 6 2 5
2 7 8 5 9
4 1 9 7 7

> In the above array we need to look at the first `row` and find `min` and `max` , And then change their `columns`.
>   So the min and max in the first row are 1 and 9 and the answer should be
>   `9` 5 `1` 4  2
>   `3` 4 `6` 7  9
>   `6` 4 `9` 2  5
>   `8` 7 `2` 5  9
>   `9` 1 `4` 7  7
>   The columns swapped are highlighted . 
>   I have tried to solve this problem with the the following code .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int array[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int max = array[0];
int min = array[0];
int indexOfMax = 0;
int indexOfMin = 0;
int n, m;
cout << "n = "; cin >> n;
cout << "m = "; cin >> m;

int **array = new int *[n]; // for the output of a random array
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   array[i] = new int [m];

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));   

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    // loop for the array
   for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
       array[i][j] = rand() % 20;
       cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        if(array[i] > max)   // finding the max in first row
        {
           max = array[i];
           indexOfMax = i;
        }
        if(array[i] < min)  // finding the min in the first row
        {
        min = indexOfMin;
        indexOfMin = i;
        }
        cout << indexOfMin << " " << indexOfMax << endl; 
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

So, primarily I get this `main.cpp:16:11: error: conflicting declaration ‘int** array’`. And then i would like to know how to swap the columns of `min` and `max` ?

Comment: You already have one variable named `array`, created in the first line of `main`. Then you try to create `int**` with the same name.

Comment: Should I change the names ?

Comment: Well, as the compiler error tells you, you cannot have two variables with the same names. How would you distinguish them?

Comment: What for is the `int array[5]` anyway since you let the user enter the dimensions?

Comment: Don't use pointers and dynamic allocation, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) for [generation of random numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). I also recommend [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to find the min/max pair. Finally [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) could be useful.

Comment: Because without `int array[5]` I cannot initialize `int max = array[0]`. @J.Doe

Comment: It's not like you couldn't do `int max = 0;`? That's really what you're doing. And for `min` it's even worse because then `min` will *always* be `0`, no matter the actual minimum value generated.

Comment: @Dr.lackedu So the first row is always swapped with the third row?

Comment: No ! the columns should swap . Read the question please

Comment: @Dr.lackedu Oh. mixed up rows and cols.

Comment: @J.Doe, I have pointed an arrow , hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @Dr.lackedu You don't need the extra array which you have in your code. Check the solution that I have posted below.

Comment: @Dr.lackedu Advice -- when you're trying to solve problems like this, do **not** use random numbers.  The reason is that every time you run your program and find there is a bug, the numbers / data will change.  That makes the problem more difficult if the target keeps moving.  Work with known, fixed data first, as is described in your question, not random numbers.  Once you get it working with fixed data, *then* you introduce the random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the extra array which you have mentioned in the code.

Working solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
int indexOfFirstRowMax;
int indexOfFirstRowMin;
int n, m;
cout << "n = "; cin >> n;
cout << "m = "; cin >> m;

int **array = new int *[n]; // for the output of a random array
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = new int[m];

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));   

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{    
for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    array[i][j] = rand() % 20;
    cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    if(i==0)
    {
    if(array[i][j] > max)   // finding the max in first row
    {
       max = array[i][j];
       indexOfFirstRowMax = j;
    }
    if(array[i][j] < min)  // finding the min in the first row
    {
       min = array[i][j];
       indexOfFirstRowMin = j;
    }
    }
}
cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"indexOfFirstRowMin = "<<indexOfFirstRowMin<<endl;
cout<<"indexOfFirstRowMax = "<<indexOfFirstRowMax<<endl; 

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    int temp = array[i][indexOfFirstRowMin];
    array[i][indexOfFirstRowMin] = array[i][indexOfFirstRowMax];
    array[i][indexOfFirstRowMax] = temp;
}
cout<<"Output after interchanging the columns"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
{
    cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <cstdlib>   // std::srand(), std::rand()
#include <ctime>     // std::time()
#include <utility>   // std::swap()
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::cin
#include <iomanip>   // std::setw()

int main()
{
    // seed the old, rusty, low entropy random number generator
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    std::cout << "rows = ";
    std::size_t rows;  // name variables with actual names instead of letters
    std::cin >> rows;  // to make them less prone to confusions

    std::cout << "columns = ";
    std::size_t columns;  // declare variables as close to where they're used
    std::cin >> columns;  // as possible

    int **array = new int *[rows];  // allocate the row pointers of our jagged array
    for (size_t row{}; row < rows; ++row) {
        array[row] = new int[columns];
        for (size_t col{}; col < columns; ++col) {
            array[row][col] = rand() % 20;  // fill the array with random numbers 0...19
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << array[row][col] << "  ";  // and also print them
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');  // add a newline after every row
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');

    std::size_t max_index{};
    std::size_t min_index{};

    // find the indexes of the maximum and the minimum in the 1st row:
    // As suggested by Some programmer dude in the comments you could
    // (and should) use std::minmax_element() ... but i guess thats some
    // assignment that wants you to do it on foot.
    for (size_t col{ 1 }; col < columns; ++col) {
        if (array[0][col] > array[0][max_index])
            max_index = col;
        if (array[0][col] < array[0][min_index])
            min_index = col;
    }

    // print them
    std::cout << "min = " << array[0][min_index] << ", max = " << array[0][max_index] << '\n';

    // swap the column min_index with the column max_index:
    for (size_t row{}; row < rows; ++row)
        std::swap(array[row][min_index], array[row][max_index]);

    // print it again:
    for (size_t row{}; row < rows; ++row) {
        for (size_t col{}; col < columns; ++col)
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << array[row][col] << "  ";
        delete[] array[row];  // and in the process clean up the mess we made
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');

    delete[] array;  // delete array of row pointers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard library facilities as suggested in my comment, you could implement it something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    std::cout << "n = ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "m = ";
    std::cin >> m;

    // Creates a matrix of N x M elements
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(n, std::vector<int>(m));

    // Create a random-number generator for the range 1 to 20 (inclusive)
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 20);

    // Generate random numbers filling our matrix
    for (auto& v : array)
    {
        std::generate(begin(v), end(v), [&]() { return dis(gen); });
    }

    // Print the matrix before swapping
    for (auto const& v : array)
    {
        std::copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // Find the min/max of the first row in the matrix
    auto minmax_pair = std::minmax_element(begin(array[0]), end(array[0]));

    // From the pair of min/max iterators fetched above, get the indexes
    auto min_index = std::distance(begin(array[0]), minmax_pair.first);
    auto max_index = std::distance(begin(array[0]), minmax_pair.second);

    // Now swap the columns of the min and max
    for (auto& v : array)
    {
        std::swap(v[min_index], v[max_index]);
    }

    // Print the matrix after swapping
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto const& v : array)
    {
        std::copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```